# qtranslate quicktags not working with php echo or static html

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress website and i'm using qtranslate.

Qtranslate has quicktags so you can translate text in your theme or custom fields etc. but it doesn't work in my theme.

I've tried the [:en] [:nl] version and the     version.

I a'm echoing the text with php and I tought maybe that was the problem but it also won't work with static html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this:

```
<?php _e("<!--:en-->english text<!--:--><!--:de-->german text<!--:-->"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

[:es]spanish text[:][:en]english text[:]